# Ошибка в коде list index out of range

Tags: python

В чем может быть проблема? Нужно выводить последние строки с файла (Снизу в верх)
Буду благодарен за решение данной проблемы, я просто чайник и пишу для теста это)

Код:

```
def famloglast(peer_id, user_id, family, strok):
    if family in familyall:
        if family == 'test1':
            if user_id in DostupID:
                textlog = Test1_FileLog.read()
                logstroki = textlog.split('\n')
                logstroki.reverse()
                strok = int(strok)
                i = 1
                logoutput = []
                for i in range(strok):
                    logoutput.append(logstroki[i]) #Это 122 строка
                    i=i-1
                if i == 1:
                    logoutput.reverse()
                    output = '\n'.join(logoutput)
                    send_message(peer_id, output)
```

```
famloglast(1234, 1234, test1, 10)
```

Ошибка:

```
line 122, in famloglast
    logoutput.append(logstroki[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Обратите внимание, я обновил ответ в части 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В вашем `logstroki` количество символов оказывается меньше, чем требует переменная `strok`. В результате вы выходите за границу и вам выдается ошибка (так как кода исполняемого вы не привели, то точно мне не проверить, но должно это быть причиной).
2. Обратите также внимание, что `i=1` пропадает зря, так как `for i in range(strok):` устанавливает i в 0. И `i=i-1` тоже не к месту, там уже итератор управляет этим i. Это в любом случае нужно исправлять. Решите, что вы хотите, так как итератор делает +1 на каждом шаге, а вы пытаетесь делать -1. Срабатывает это только на самом последнем шаге. Фактически после цикла ваш i всегда будет равен `strok - 2`. Так что `i == 1` сработает только при strok = 3.

Answer (score 2):

по поводу ошибки вам уже подсказали, а на счет получения последних строк, вы можете заменить свой цикл на это, и реверс делать не надо:

```
output = '\n'.join(logstroki[-strok:])
```